# Valid date format check in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

When I execute the below code I get a 'True' even though the date which I supply is incorrect (2010-55-04). Could someone please clarify why that is the case.

```
package basic;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class VerifyIfStrngIsValidDate {

    public static boolean checkdate(String dt1)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        System.out.println(df1.toPattern());
        df1.setLenient(false);
        try {
            df1.parse(dt1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean res;
        res=checkdate("2010-55-04");
        System.out.println(res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your format is wrong. `mm` is minutes. You meant `MM` for months.

Comment: Because 55 *minutes* is valid. Try `MM` for *month* instead.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why SimpleDateFormat is giving Month as January instead of October in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454024/5221149)

Comment: @Elliot, Andreas, Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @user3807741 Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Many hundreds of code examples would have been found, against which comparing your own code would have exposed your error. Also, some searching would have taught you are using troublesome old date-time classes that wore supplanted years ago by the java.time classes.

Comment: Any particular reason why in 2018 you are using the outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class? I recommen you forget everything about it and start using [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate.parse("2010-55-04")`. No need for an explicit formatter, so no possibility of getting it wrong. And it *will* throw an exception because of the month value being out of range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format mask for year-month-date.  Use `M` for months, not `m`, which is minutes:

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You will see that the demo below now fails after making this change.

### Demo

Comment: For such an obvious duplicate question, isn’t it better to provide a link to an original than to give a new answer? I think it would help us keep all the information in one place, for the benefit of all.

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree.  Actually it didn't even occur to me to mark this as a duplicate, but yes there are probably dozens of other SDF questions which could be used to resolve the OP.